# How to set testEnvironment: 'node' config dynamically

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, ts-jest, end-to-end

I initially had a bunch of tests written in jest for my NextJS app located in `src/tests/components/*.test.tsx`. I'm now trying to write my first end-to-end tests under `src/tests/end-to-end/*.test.tsx`.

I'm having issues running both types of tests together as they require different test environment configurations. For the component tests, I need to use `testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'`, but for the end-to-end tests, I need to use `testEnvironment: 'node'`.

Is there a way for me to set the test environment to `node` but only when running the E2E tests? What's the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes one idea is to use a node envelope file that can store what env you are in.
After installing dotenv with npm i dotenv, you create a .env file at the root of your repo.

In the file add: ENVIRONMENT=prod

Then in the file you need to reference your variable, follow as below.
ex.

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const obj = {
    testEnvironment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'prod' ? 'node' : 'otherSetting'
}
```

Comment: Duh.. I can't believe I didn't think of environment variables. Thank you!