How to refactor my index.js page so that my db connection isn't called when running tests
I'm building an API and used a tutorial as a basis, but it didn't cover testing, so I'm looking too add testing as I'm going. But when I import my app object into the test it's running all the code (as expected) to get the routes, but my db connection logic is getting called too, so in the tests, the db connection triggers.
How do I refactor my index page so that I can call the app object without having to have the db connection logic called as well.
This is to run the tests locally, as unit tests before I'd push to my repo to ensure I've not broken any other endpoints, logic etc.
I'm using Express/JS/Mocha
Here is my index file:
require('./Models/UsersModel')
const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes')
const requireAuth = require('../src/middlewares/requireAuth')


const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(authRoutes)

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT

const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {})
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('connected to dev-cluster')
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('error connecting to dev-cluster')
    console.log(err)
})


app.get('/', requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.send(`${req.user.email}`)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app started on port:${PORT} `)
})

And here is an example test:
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../src/index'); 

describe('Authentication Routes', () => {
    it('POST /login should respond with 200 and user data', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .post('/login')
            .send({ username: 'testuser', password: 'testpass' });
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('user');
    });

    it('POST /register should respond with 201 and user data', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .post('/register')
            .send({ username: 'newuser', password: 'newpass' });
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
        expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('user');
    });

    it('GET /logout should respond with 200', async () => {
        const response = await request(app).get('/logout');
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});

Any other tips/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks very much!

You should implement test environment, see about integration test and unit test. When you are running test, usually you should have an test environment with different database connection and etc.

@VagnerWentz the aim is to run the tests locally, before pushing to the remote repo, like unit tests. I've not yet got to hosting the code for test environments.

It looks like you haven't done a unit test but an integration test. You may notice that since you're requesting a post and the route, you're calling the first thing from the backend and then the route will execute what's inside it. If you don't have an test environment like, separated database and etc your code will execute the default.

ah ok, thank you. You're correct. I've done some reading into unit vs integration testing. I still have the issue in which when I run the tests, it tries to connect to the db and then the process hangs as if it's running the application normally.
how do I get this to stop?

First of all, you should have another database for testing if you want. Then, you should configure the test environment. You can refer to this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483453/how-to-set-testenvironment-node-config-dynamically. You should have separate environments for production, testing, and development, and load the configuration based on the current environment

This API now connects to and saves data to an instance of MongoDB. I don't need a production environment at the moment. I'm just learning react native, one env is plenty. I know I'll need to set up CI/CD in the future for other envs.
